# get leads information from Zoho crm using api

Tags: php, zoho

I need to get the information of a lead from crm, using the rest api and php how can I acomplish this?

I am using the code below but it is giving me an error, "4500Problem occured while processing the request", it in a php file called index and using wamp to run it, is this enought or what is missing?

```
$authtoken = 'mytokennumber';

$name = 'client name';

$xmlData='<Lead><FirstName>'.$name.'</FirstName></Lead>';

$ch = curl_init('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$query = "newFormat=1&authtoken={$authtoken}&scope=crmapi&xmlData={$xmlData}"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

can you help me ? thanks

Comment: You can use curl. If it is public API, accessible globally curl can read data from provided url. But don't think that someone will code it for you. Learn more about curl and how api you want to read from works.

Comment: hi thanks for the response I edit the question to be more especific, hope it helps

Comment: Your code looks ok. The error you got is sent by crm. Maybe you are not allowed to insert leads or something. You have to read crm docs. And I'll suggest you to build postdata using `http_build_query function`. Code is more readable and it is harder to make a typo.